# Trying to understand [expr.const] in C++14

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr

Where in the C++14 Standard, does it prohibit the **declaration** of object `a` below?

```
class A{ int i = 1; public: A():i{1}{} };

int main()
{
    constexpr A a{};
}
```

See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5f97eb7378bfc56)

Note that I highlighted the word **declaration**, because I don't think bullet points (2.7.2) or (2.7.3), in §5.19[expr.const]p2 is an answer for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dcl.constexpr]p9:

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object ***shall have literal type*** and shall be initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, ***that call shall be a constant expression*** (5.19). [...]

The error you're getting now is because your type is not a literal type. Your type is not a literal type because it does have a custom constructor, but doesn't have any `constexpr` constructor. The wording in the error message is rather clear about the exact requirements.

If you add a `constexpr` constructor (but not the default constructor), the error message changes:

```
class A{ int i = 1; public: A():i{1}{} constexpr A(int){} };

int main()
{
    constexpr A a{};
}
```

Now the error message becomes

```
error: call to non-constexpr function ‘A::A()’
     constexpr A a{};
```

This is the second part I bolded: it's not the initialiser that has to be a constant expression. You're right, your initialiser isn't an expression at all. It's the constructor call that must be a constant expression, and although it isn't expressed explicitly in the source code, it is an expression nonetheless. This is covered in [expr.const] rather clearly:

> - an invocation of a function other than a `constexpr` constructor for a literal class, a `constexpr` function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor (12.4) [...]

to which you already refer in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your default constructor is not `constexpr`. Therefore, you cannot create a default constructed `constexpr` object.

Comment: But where in the Standard does it say this? Remember there is no *expression* in the declaration `constexpr A{};`.